# netbeans IDE: how to delete data source

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, datasource, persistence-unit

I have a Java Web application that contains a Persistence unit. In this persistence unit I can select an existing data source or create a new data source. When I run this web application on the build in glassfish server, the data source is created on the build in glassfish server. Also a connection pool is created.

I can delete the data source and / or connection pool on the build in glassfish server. This does not delete the data source from the Netbeans IDE. When I run the web application again, the data sources and connection pools are recreated.

How can I delete the data source and connection pools in the netbeans IDE? I can't find this functionality anywhere.

I want to delete the existing data sources and connection pools because I have an problem with a new data source / connection pool. To make sure that there is no mix up happening somewhere between the data sources / connection pools I want to remove the old ones that I am not using anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file you are looking for is called *glassfish-resources.xml* (or *sun-resources.xml*). It stores all the server resources that are deployed with your application. It can be found in the setup directory of your project (in Netbeans "Files" tag).

Answer (score 8):

You have to go to services window (Ctrl + 5) and expand Severs > GlassFish Server (version) > Resources > JDBC Resources and locate the unnecessary data sources. Right click and select Unregister. This will remove appearing it in all the Netbeans Projects.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans takes the Data Sources from the GlassFish. You can find/edit the domain.xml. Alternatively, you can edit via GF's admin console.

Comment: deleting in the glassfish admin console worked for me, this can be accessed through the GUI

Answer (score 1):

Go to context.xml and remove the line containing "**Resource**" entry  .

Then remove the  corresponding "resource-ref" entry from web.xml.

Then clean and build the project.

This has solved the data source  problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **netbeans 8.0.2**

In **projects** tab of left most panel search your project tree. There is a node **other resources**. Traverse this node please. **glassfish-resources.xml** is a leaf there under the **setup**. I found all the jdbc and other resources there.

Means **Other Resources -> setup -> glassfish-resources.xml**

[image]